# Nginx Reverse Proxy Will Not Load HTTPS Sites

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, https

Today has been the first time I've used Nginx. I got it set up as a dedicated reverse proxy by following a few guides. This is what I'm trying to recreate - http://www.integratedwebsystems.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/06/reverse_proxy.jpg

I have it working fine with port 80 but anything loaded over HTTPS gives me errors about HTTP content being insecure. Trying to load any HTTPS site over the reverse proxy via the internet looks very wrong. Loading it internally works just fine.

Example - https://i.stack.imgur.com/90Mfc.png - That is supposed to be the Wordpress admin console, it looks like something out of the 90s.

Below is the nginx config I'm using -

```
server {
   listen 80;
   server_name domain1.com;
   location / {
      proxy_pass http://192.168.1.149/;
      proxy_set_header Host $host;
   }
}

# HTTPS server

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name domain1.com;

    error_log /tmp/error.log;

        ssl on;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/server.key;
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/server.crt;


    location / {
        proxy_pass http://192.168.1.149/;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
    }
}
```

Can anyone advise me on what I'm missing to get HTTPS working correctly over the reverse proxy?

Comment: FWIW, the raw look of the page is caused by the browser refusing to load the CSS via plain HTTP when the HTML was retrieved via HTTPS.

Answer (score 2):

You're not missing anything; you configured nginx correctly.

The problem here is that WordPress thinks it should be generating HTTP links. When you try to access it via HTTPS, it still generates all of its links with `http://` and thus they can't be loaded (without explicitly loading insecure content in the browser).

There are WordPress plugins that will convert your admin console to https, if that is what you are trying to do. You could also edit your blog's General Settings and convert the entire site to https quickly and easily, without a plugin.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. It feels like something is still a little off. Loading the Wordpress site directly from the server I can access the whole site off of https without a problem.

Earlier I installed this HTTPS plugin to wordpress and told it to force https on the admin console but it didn't make a difference - http://wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-https/

Comment: There probably is something still a little off. But you didn't describe the other server. So it's hard to say.

Comment: The Nginx error logs give this for 443 connections - 

2014/06/18 17:22:38 [error] 1639#0: *15 upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header from upstream, client: 50.83.1X6.1X3, server: domain1.com, request: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1", upstream: "https://192.168.1.149:443/favicon.ico", host: "domain1.com"

Comment: The other internal webservers are all running Apache2 on Ubuntu server.

Answer (score 0):

If you can afford it, you can try re-encrypting the traffic:

```
location / {
    proxy_pass https://192.168.1.149/;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
}
```

The appserver will then be aware of the SSL, obviously.

Another way is to configure an alternate Apache port, e.g.

```
location / {
    proxy_pass http://192.168.1.149:444/;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
}
```

with a vhost that sets appropriate flags to make Wordpress/PHP believe that the request had actually been encrypted, e.g.

```
SetEnv SSL=on
```

It can be tricky to catch all necessary/sufficient settings.